# Use data-* attribute as tooltip for jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I want to use some `data-*` attribute as content for jQuery UI tooltip.

I've look at several examples in this answers:

- [JQuery UI Tooltip with data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495452/jquery-ui-tooltip-with-data-attributes)
- [jQuery Tooltip that doesn't use the <title> attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039030/jquery-tooltip-that-doesnt-use-the-title-attribute)

but I can't make it work properly...

Here's my code:

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/P2XhC/

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_1">number 1</div>
<div id="div_2">number 2</div>
<div id="div_3">number 3</div>

<button id="btn_class">STEP 1: Add class to 1 and 3</button>
<button id="btn_tooltip">STEP 2: Add tooltip to class</button>
<button id="btn_check">STEP 3: Check for data</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#btn_class").click(function()
{
    $("#div_1, #div_3").addClass("tooltip").data("text", "show this!");
});

$("#btn_tooltip").click(function()
{
    $(".tooltip").tooltip({
        //content: $(this).data("text"), //this doesn't work
        content: "show something...", //this works!
        items: '*'
    });
});

$("#btn_check").click(function()
{
    $("div").each(function()
    {
        console.log($(this).attr("id") + " = " + $(this).data("text");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I see tooltips when I hover over them. What's wrong here?

Comment: @swajak That's a harcoded content, remove comment from the line above in order to use the data attribute as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your back dude. In your code, `this` was referring to the clicked div, not the tooltips.

In this corrected jsfiddle, I'm iterating over each tooltip, so that `this` will refer to the current tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/P2XhC/1/

```
$("#btn_tooltip").click(function()
{
    $(".tooltip").each(function() {
        $(this).tooltip({
            content: $(this).data("text"),
            //content: "show something...",
            items: '*'
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: How did I missed that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

In this context:

```
..
content: $(this).data("text"),
..
```

'this' is actually '#btn_tooltip', changing it to a function returning the value you need will change the 'this' to be what your looking for:

```
$("#btn_class").click(function()
{
    $("#div_1, #div_3").addClass("tooltip").data("text", "show this!");
});

$("#btn_tooltip").click(function()
{
    $(".tooltip").tooltip({
        content: function() { return $(this).data("text"); },
        //content: "show something...",
        items: '*'
    });
});
```

Comment: My bad, I thought you were using an older version of jQuery and my error in code made it work.  I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over each tooltip, so that `this` will refer to current tooltip. Try this:

```
$("#btn_tooltip").click(function()
{
    $(".tooltip").each(function() {
            $(this).tooltip({
                content: $(this).data('text'),
                items: '*'
            });
        });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/P2XhC/3/)

Comment: beat you by a minute! sorry bro. Have an upvote anyways.